# #ifdef with warning if misspelled

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I would like to use preprocessor directives to check if I have to include some part of my program warning me if I did a mistake or forgot to include the header containing the options. See the following example, is there a more common way to do that with only a `#if` and a `#endif` ?

```
class Foo
{
  private:
#   if ENABLE_MULTITHREADING == 1
    boost::mutex mt;
#   elif !defined(ENABLE_MULTITHREADING)  // I would like to remove
#     error                               // theses two lines
#   endif
};
```

Comment: If it doesn't compile surely that is good enough

Comment: @EdHeal It would happily compile, it would just do the wrong thing, with valid macro definitions.

Comment: So `mt` is not used anywhere?

Comment: @EdHeal It would not surprise me if the OP's uses of `mt` are guarded by that same `ENABLE_MULTITHREADING` conditional.

Comment: Refactor your code so it only has the one `#ifdef` and check very carefully for no spelling mistakes

Comment: It's only an example. I use it also for licences protection of the software, for example, and other build options. I want to be sure when I check an option, I really checked it and not a not existing due to a mistake. (and why -1 ? What is stupid in my question ?)

Comment: this line of reasoning is too broad, e.g. you might next wonder how to detect the typo `if ( x == 24 )` when actually you wanted to check `if ( x == 34 )`. At some point you just have to write correct code.  You could set up a test suite that will catch any erroneous behaviour regardless of whether it was due to a typo or otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to use `#error`.

```
#if ENABLE_MULTITHREADING != 1
# error ENABLE_MULTITHREADING needs to be 1
#endif
```

Also beware: your checks seem *very* odd. In the first check, you're checking the value of `ENABLE_MULTITHREADING`. In the second check, you're checking whether `ENABLE_MULTITHREADING` is defined. Consider what happens when `ENABLE_MULTITHREADING` is defined as `0`: neither your `#if` nor your `#elif`'s condition is true.

Using a single check means there's less chance of such inconsistencies.

If it's actually your intent to check that `ENABLE_MULTITHREADING` is defined, regardless of its value, then

```
#ifndef ENABLE_MULTITHREADING
# error ENABLE_MULTITHREADING needs to be defined
#endif
```

but this does not allow you to use a single check: you'd still need to check the value of `ENABLE_MULTITHREADING` later on.

If what you're really after *isn't* a check for `ENABLE_MULTITHREADING`, but to check that a specific file got included, then I'd actually say you shouldn't be using *any* check. Simply include the specific file.

Comment: He wants to guard against errors like `#ifdef ENABLE_MULTITHREDAING`  `foo = 5;` `#endif`  which will silently behave wrong

Comment: @MattMcNabb That's what I focused on in the first part of my answer: if you make sure you only have a single check, then at least all checks will check for exactly the same thing. (I mentioned subtly different checks with the same name, but it applies equally to the same checks with subtly different names.) But it's only one of the things the OP wants to guard against, another one that's mentioned in the question is forgetting to include the header that defines `ENABLE_MULTITHREADING`.

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor is usually a bad idea. Just create a stub for the case of not enabled multi-threaded. Then just have the guard in the declaration. The rest of the code will be fine.